# When does variables in Ruby determine whether to hold a new reference?

Tags: ruby

I learned that in Ruby, variables hold references to objects, not the objects themselves.
For example:

```
a = "Tim"
b = a
a[0] = 'J'
```

Then *a* and *b* both have value "Jim".

However if I change the 3rd line to

```
a = "Jim"
```

Then *a == Jim* and *b == Tim*

I assume that means the code I changed created a new reference for *a*.

So why does changing a letter or changing the entire string make so much difference?

**Follow-up question:** Does Java work the same way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single thing to learn here is the difference between *assignment* and *method call*.

```
a = 'Jim'
```

is an assignment. You create a new string object (literal `'Jim'`) and assign it to variable `a`.

On the other side,

```
a[0] = 'J'
```

is a [method call](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001129) on an object already referenced by the variable `a`. A method call can't replace the object referenced by the variable with another one, it can just change the internal state of the object, and/or return another object.

Comment: To clarify, `a = 'Jim'` creates a new string _object_, and then sets the variable `a` to _reference_ that object. Variables are not shoeboxes; they do not _contain_ objects, but rather _reference_ them. This is also why you can't ask an object for its "name"; and once you follow the variable reference to find the object, it has no idea who directed you to it. It would be like asking someone on the street where the barber was, and then going to the barber and asking him for the name of the person that directed you to him. He is not that person, and doesn't know that person.

Answer (score 3):

I find that things like this are easiest to figure out using IRB:

```
>> a = 'Tim'
=> "Tim"
>> a.object_id
=> 2156046480
>> b = a
=> "Tim"
>> b.object_id
=> 2156046480
>> a.object_id == b.object_id
=> true
```

As you can see `a` and `b` have the same `object_id`, meaning they reference the same object. So when you change one, you change the other. Now assign something new to `a`:

```
>> a = 'Jim'
=> "Jim"
>> a.object_id
=> 2156019520
>> b.object_id
=> 2156046480
>> a.object_id == b.object_id
=> false
```

You made `a` point to a new object, while `b` still kept the old reference. Changing either of them now will not change the other one.

Comment: You've answered how to prove or determine when a variable is referencing a new object, but you have not answered the OP's question as to when this can be expected. It's good advice, but does not really answer the question, IMHO.

Comment: There was already an answer that did that, so it was more meant as additional information, which probably wasn't explicit enough.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `a[0] = 'J'`, you're asking

> Change the first character of the object referenced by `a` (which happens to be the same as `b`) to 'J'

While when you do `a = "Jim"`, you're assigning an entirely new object reference (the string `"Jim"`) to `a`. `b` is unaffected because you're not changing anything in the original reference.

Comment: Another way to think about this is that the assignment for `b` means  `b` holds a reference to the object that `a` references, it doesn't hold a reference to `a` (which is not possible in ruby, afaik)

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar with integers? I tried 'a = 5 b = a a += 1' and got different values for a and b. I guess using the assignment operator in the usual way always results in creating a new object reference?

Comment: Actually as `Fixnum`s are immutable, what `+=` does is it returns another Fixnum object. Try: `p 2.object_id; a = 1; a += 1; p a.object_id`

Comment: Moreover, `a+=1` is a shorthand for `a = a+1`, and so you can see that first you evaluate `a+1`, which _is a new object_, and then you assign `a` to reference to that object.